# Set DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValue in WPF with Code

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a DataTable that is coming from a Web Service, which I need to bind to a ComboBox. I have not grokked doing binding in XAML yet so this question is about binding in code instead. So far I have tried

```
        cboManager.DataContext = Slurp.DistrictManagerSelect().DefaultView;
        cboManager.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
        cboManager.SelectedValuePath = "NameListId";
        cboManager.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding());
```

And I have tried

```
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        tbl = Slurp.DistrictManagerSelect();
        cboManager.ItemsSource = ((IListSource)tbl).GetList();
        cboManager.DisplayMemberPath = "[Name]";
        cboManager.SelectedValuePath = "[NameListId]";
        DataContext = this;
```

In both cases I get the list of managers to show but when I select from the ComboBox I get [Name] and [NameListId] and not the values I am expecting. What am I doing wrong (other than not using XAML's DataBinding)?

**Edit added** after answers to my original post came in.

So (based on Rachel's response) try number three looks like this:

```
            using (DataTable tbl = Slurp.DistrictManagerSelect())
            {
                List<ManagerList> list = new List<ManagerList>();
                foreach (var row in tbl.Rows)
                {
                    list.Add(new ManagerList 
                    { 
                        NameListId = (int)row[0],                           
                        Name = row[1].ToString()  
                    });
                }
            }
```

Assuming I am doing what she meant the correct way I am no getting this error **Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just bind to the DataTable directly?  Do you have columns Name and NameListId?  Leave off the DataContext (you already assigned the ItemsSource).

```
    DataTable tbl = Slurp.DistrictManagerSelect(); 
    cboManager.ItemsSource = tbl;
    cboManager.DisplayMemberPath = "Name"; 
    cboManager.SelectedValuePath = "NameListId";
```

When you cast to the IListSource I suspect it is combining all the columns.  If you want to bind to a list then you need to create items that have properties Name and NameListID.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because your `ItemsSource` is a `DataTable`, so each ComboBoxItem contains a DataContext of a `DataRow`, and the `DataRow` class doesn't have properties called `Name` or `NameListId`

Basically, you're trying to tell the ComboBox to display `DataRow.Name`, and set the value to `DataRow.NameListId`, both of which are not valid properties.

I usually prefer to parse data into objects, and bind the `ItemsSource` a `List<MyObject>` or `ObservableCollection<MyObject>`

```
foreach(DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
    list.Add(new MyObject { Name = row[0].ToString(), NameListId = (int)row[1] });

cboManager.ItemsSource = list;
```

Comment: Rachel I need some clarification on your answer. Do I have the right idea (my added edit)? And what do I need to do to make that work?

Comment: @BukHix Remove the square brackets from your `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath`. My best guess is the error comes from trying to bind to `ManagerList[Name]`, which is invalid. You want it to bind to `ManagerList.Name` instead.

Comment: I am getting the error on these two line NameListId = (int)row[0], and Name = row[1].ToString() so I am not even to the point where the Manager.List comes in. Currently the only code I am using is what was posted in the edit (I removed the DisplayMember and SelectedValue paths).

Comment: @BukHix Oh, I might have some compiler errors there. I was typing that without a compiler and haven't been working much with with C# lately. Try changing the `var` in the `foreach` loop to `DataRow`. It's probably creating `row` as an `object` instead of a `DataRow`